# Gwibber is not using Indicator Applet or loading on start up

Tags: 10.10, applet, indicator, notification, gwibber

I'm currently using the 10.10 beta of Ubuntu with the most recent updates installed. When I boot up the computer, gwibber fails to start up and when I do open it, it shows an icon in the notification area (which I do not want) and it doesn't use the indicator applet at all (even when closed).

[image: notification bar] [image: menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Gwibber.

I solved it editing the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/gwibber.desktop` (in a terminal, put: `sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/gwibber.desktop` without the quotation marks) and changing the value of "X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay" from 30 to 5.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have python-indicate installed?  It would be installed by default, but might not be installed on upgrade if you had removed it in the past.

If you don't have python-indicate, install that and restart gwibber.

If you do have python-indicate, please look in the log file at ~/.cache/gwibber/gwibber.log for anything interesting and maybe run gwibber-service in debug mode to collect more info:

```
gwibber-service -d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to start on startup make sure its on the list and checked in the services/startup items settings. If it isn't there add gwibber after login make sure     gwibber-service is running(its what does the indicator applet I think).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I do have python-indicate installed and I couldn't find anything that can point me out to what's going on on the log files. I noticed that I had 3 or 4 log files. So, to be able to know which one was the one I just decided to delete all the log files. And after that Gwibber worked, now it's showing in the indicator applet :)